# Is it possible to debug BIOS image in GDB?

Tags: debugging, gdb, qemu, bios

I have a custom bios ( I actually have the image of the SPI Flash Bios, but in my opinion it should be the same ) and I would like to debug with GDB. Is it possible to run with GDB ? I know where there is the first executed instruction ( 0h3FFFF0 ) inside the file, and the files it should be a sequence of assembler instruction. Is there a way to follow the flow and run step by step the bios ?

Comment: the most important thing that is missing in this question is exact hardware on which those binary was executed. Is it x86 ?

Comment: Also if you can provide reason for your need maybe I can give you more help.

Answer (score 0):

First, it's incorrect to assume that SPI image will contain only BIOS executable. It usually much more then that (ie. ME, Setup parameters, flash descriptor). To investigate what is inside your image I suggest to use `binwalk <spi_image>`, if you will be lucky, it will detect layout of your image. Then you can extract image parts by `binwalk -e <spi_image>`.

Second, since I don't know if we talk about modern hardware or some obsolete I will try to be general. I don't think GDB is able to run BIOS binary because those binaries doesn't contain any debugging information that GDB can understand. GDB need to know what executable file it deals with, what is the ABI used and what is the physical architecture of target being debugged. Even if it will know all those information the code could be only disassembled because BIOS starts with low level hardware initialization, which cannot be recreated in GDB. On the other hand modern hardware BIOS (UEFI firmware) is typically signed.

What is the best thing you can do with extracted BIOS binary is to get datasheet of your hardware and use disassembler like `IDA Pro` or `radare2` to investigate code flow.